# Azure Data Factory - Storing Inline Passwords

Tags: azure, security, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that starts by going to a REST API to obtain an authorization token. In order to obtain this token, the initial POST request needs to contain a username, password, and private key in the request body. It looks like this:

```
{
  "Username": "<myusername>",
  "Password": "<mypassword>",
  "PrivateKey":"<privatekey>"
}
```

Currently I just have this stored as plain text in the Web activity in ADF

[image]

To me this doesn't seem very secure and I'm wondering if there is a better way to store this JSON string. I've looked into Azure Key Vault, but that seems to be for storing "data store" credentials.... What is the best practice for storing credentials like this to be used by ADF?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the individual values as Secrets in Key vault and fetch them individually via Web activity from KeyVault with masked output thereby making your ADF secure.
Below GITHUb location contains the Pipeline JSON :
https://github.com/NandanHegde15/Azure-DataFactory-Generic-Pipelines/blob/main/Get%20Secret%20From%20KeyVault/Pipeline/GetSecretFromKeyVault.json

Other way would be to use SecureString Parameter
[image]

But would say to avoid using the parameter and leverage the Key Vault

Answer (score 0):

the credentials can be saved in the key vault secret
The secret can be called for authentication in the linked service that connects to the required base url
[Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-an-http-source-using-ui](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-http?tabs=data-factory#create-a-linked-service-to-an-http-source-using-ui)